# Deriving Vieta formula for polynomials

Tags: polynomials, roots

So I just learned the Vieta formula for both the quadratic and cubic form. I am wondering if there is a form of the Vieta formula for polynomials with more than just 3 terms, and if there is one, is there any way to quickly derive it for a polynomial with many roots so that I can use it?

Comment: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta's_formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas)

Comment: Just multiply $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)\cdots $ out and compare the coefficients

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a polynomial of the form $f(x)=a_nx^n+\cdots+a_1x+a_0$. We can w.l.o.g. assume that $a_n=1$ as this does not change anything about the roots and makes the following a bit easier.

Suppose you know all the roots, let's call them $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$ (there are exactly $n$ counted with multiplicity by the fundamental theorem of algebra). Then:

$$f(x)=(x-\alpha_1)\cdots(x-\alpha_n)$$

And here the fun begins. We note that $(-1)^n\alpha_1\cdots\alpha_n=a_0$ as this is the only term not containing any $x$. We also note that $-(\alpha_1+\cdots+\alpha_n)=a_{n-1}$ as these are all terms of with power $x^{n-1}$. Similarily you can obtain all the Vieta relations (but they are a bit messy in between). For example:

$$\alpha_1\alpha_2+\alpha_1\alpha_3+\cdots+\alpha_{n-1}\alpha_n=\sum_{1\le i<j\le n} \alpha_i\alpha_j=a_{n-2}$$

In general, the coefficients will be so-called [elementary symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) (as stated on the Wikipedia page as well) in the roots.

Comment: "Then" on line $6$ is not obvious. It would not be obvious to anyone who sees it for the first time